# How to get the auth token in incognito window in a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am using chrome.identity.getAuthToken to get the oauth token but the identity Api is disabled in incognito window So I am not able to process my extension Suggest any other possible way to get the token in incognito window

Comment: Send a [message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) and call getAuthToken in the background script's onMessage listener.

Comment: In background script whether the identity Api will be available in incognito mode ???

Comment: Yes, if you didn't add "incognito":"split" in manifest.json.

Comment: I didn’t add the split mode in manifest Json . Now should I use the chrome.identity.getauthtoken in background js to get the token ??

Comment: How should I return the token from background js to my file where I need the token to fetch the details from the API

Comment: My first comment already answered that: use messaging as shown in the documentation, for example respond with sendResponse or send another message.

Comment: I used messaging in background js and I got the token in incognito window. But if I login two different users in normal and incognito window . Now I get the token of the user which is logged in the Normal window. But I need to get the token of the user in incognito window

Comment: I guess this API can't be used in an incognito window after all.

Comment: Kindly suggest me a way in which I can get auth token in both normal window and incognito window